# PDO not inserting correct data

Tags: php, pdo

I have this function, which I pass a table name, and data into.

```
public function quickInsert($table, $data) {
    $keys = array_keys($data);

    $keysStr = '`'.implode('`,`', $keys).'`';
    $valStr = ':'.implode(',:', $keys);
    $Sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` ($keysStr) VALUES ($valStr)";
    dump($Sql);
    $st = $this->connection->prepare($Sql);
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        dump(':'.$k.' - '.$v);
        $st->bindParam(':'.$k, $v);
    }
    //dump($st->execute());
}
```

The output from the dumps is

```
string(114) "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`,`password`,`first_name`,`last_name`) VALUES (:email,:password,:first_name,:last_name)"

string(21) ":email - my@email.com"

string(140) ":password - myHashedPasswordString"

string(17) ":first_name - Tom"

string(17) ":last_name - Hart"
```

However, when I execute the query, the data in all the fields is the last name (In this case "Hart").

What have I gotten wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$v` is overwritten on each iteration of the loop, when it is finished and `$st->execute()` runs it only contains the last value. Try `$st->bindValue()` instead of `$st->bindParam()`.

Comment: Perfect, th ank you very much, I didn't know bindParam worked like that :).

Comment: I can't for 7 minutes, I will soon as I can